# Check to see if two arrays have similar keys and print the value of the second array, if they don't match jump one cell

Tags: php, arrays, tcpdf

I have two arrays, one contains all the keys extracted from the database and the second one contains some of the keys in the first array. ( The first array contains data of all the subjects a student is supposed to seat for and the second one contains some of the keys if the student hasn't sat for the paper and the marks for the specific subject.)

The arrays look like this.

This is the first array

```
$getAllSubjects($class_id) = {210, 221, 222, 223};
```

The second array.

```
$subjectIDs = {210 => 20, 223 => 9}
```

The student has done two subjects (second array) out of the four subjects (in the first array).

My Objective is to print values (marks) from the second array if there is a key match on both arrays.

I have tried using PHP in built function in_array() and produced results but I expect it to jump one cell if the keys don't match because am using tcpdf to generate PDF.

```
 foreach ($results_ as $row) {


        $smarks = $row['mar'];
        $integerIDs = explode(',', $smarks);
        asort($integerIDs);

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        $subjects_ = $row['subjects_'];
        $subjectIDs = explode(',', $subjects_);
        asort($subjectIDs);

        $subject_count = count($subjectIDs);

        $average = round($row['m'] / $subject_count, 2);

        $total_subject_marks = $exam_out_of * $subject_count;

        $SubjectPercentage = round(($row['m'] / $total_subject_marks) * 100);
        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------

        $pdf->Cell($width_cell[5], 7, $row['s'], $border=1,$ln=0,'C',$fill=$fill, $link='', $stretch=0, $ignore_min_height=false, $calign='T', $valign='R');
        $pdf->Cell($width_cell[2], 7, $row['FirstName'] . " " . $row['OtherNames'] . " " . $row['LastName'], $border=1,$ln=0,'L',$fill=$fill, $link='', $stretch=0, $ignore_min_height=false, $calign='T', $valign='R');
        $pdf->Cell($width_cell[4], 7, $row['RollId'],$border=1,$ln=0,'L',$fill=$fill, $link='', $stretch=0, $ignore_min_height=false, $calign='T', $valign='R');

            for($i=0; $i < count(getAllSubjects($class_id)); $i++){
                if(in_array($subjectIDs[$i], getAllSubjects($class_id))){
                    $pdf->Cell($width_cell[4], 7, $integerIDs[$i] ,$border=1,$ln=0,'C',$fill=true, $link='', $stretch=0, $ignore_min_height=false, $calign='T', $valign='R');
                }else{
                    $pdf->Cell($width_cell[4], 7, "_" ,$border=1,$ln=0,'C',$fill=true, $link='', $stretch=0, $ignore_min_height=false, $calign='T', $valign='R');
                }
            }

        $pdf->setX(238);
    
        $pdf->Cell($width_cell[4], 7, $row['m'], $border=1,$ln=0,'C',$fill=$fill, $link='', $stretch=0, $ignore_min_height=false, $calign='T', $valign='R');
        $pdf->Cell($width_cell[4], 7, $average , $border=1,$ln=0,'C',$fill=$fill, $link='', $stretch=0, $ignore_min_height=false, $calign='T', $valign='R');
        $pdf->Cell($width_cell[4], 7, $exam_out_of, $border=1,$ln=0,'C',$fill=true, $link='', $stretch=0, $ignore_min_height=false, $calign='T', $valign='R');

        $SubjectPercentages = round($SubjectPercentage);

            if($SubjectPercentages >= 96){
                $grade = "EX";
            }elseif ($SubjectPercentages >= 86 && $SubjectPercentages <= 95) {
                $grade = "VG";
            }elseif($SubjectPercentages >=70 && $SubjectPercentages <= 85 ){
                $grade = "G";
            }elseif ($SubjectPercentages >= 50 && $SubjectPercentages <= 69) {
                $grade = "P";
            }else {
                $grade = "F";
            }

        $pdf->Cell($width_cell[10], 7, $grade   ,$border=1,$ln=1,'C',$fill=true, $link='', $stretch=0, $ignore_min_height=false, $calign='T', $valign='R');

        $fill = !$fill; $cnt = $cnt + 1;
    }
```

This is the current outcome

[image]

My expected outcome from the table should be the marks allocated (9) to Mohamed Ali Abubakar (number 25 on the table ) should be on column 8 right above marks 273, but is placed on the first cell. On the far right are the totals of the marks obtained.

Comment: Could you add some code you have try ?

Comment: You need to share with us (sample) array data so we can reproduce. Clearly state (with an example) the current outcome vs. the expected outcome. Where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we have all ins and outs, but i have try this way (i didn't touch tcpdf section since i don't have it) :

```
$results_ = [
    ['mar' => '210 => 20, 223 => 9', 'subjects_' => '210, 221, 222, 223', 'm' => 29],
    ['mar' => '210 => 30, 223 => 12', 'subjects_' => '210, 221, 222, 223', 'm' => 42],
];

foreach ($results_ as $row) {
    $subjects_ = $row['subjects_'];
    $subjectIDs = explode(', ', $subjects_);
    asort($subjectIDs);

    // prepare final marks by subject id for key and zero 0 value attributed by default.
    $marks = \array_fill_keys($subjectIDs, 0);
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

    $smarks = $row['mar'];
    // fill $marks keys subject by real mark attribute
    $marksBySubject = \array_map(
        function(string $elem) use (&$marks) {
            $details = \explode(' => ', $elem);
            $marks[\trim($details[0])] = (float) \trim($details[1]);
        },
        explode(', ', $smarks)
    );

//    print_r($marks);
//    Array
//    (
//        [210] => 30
//        [221] => 0
//        [222] => 0
//        [223] => 12
//    )

    // now marks contains all marks for all subjects, if a mark is missing it will be zero attributed.
}
```

We prepare `$marks` to be an array, its keys would be subject ids and values by default zero, thus we can handle offset in your pdf output.